# Can you place two fixed divs next to each other?

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

Currently I am working on my online-portfolio. I need to create two divs that are fixed and do not scroll. They both need to be the height of the page. The content in the middle however needs to scroll. the two bars left and right need to stay fixed (see picture)

My current code for the left div is the following:

```
.content_left {
  background-color: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 10%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help and support! I am greatful with any advice and open to all kinds of solutions.

[divs labeld 1&2 are the divs I need to be fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTS2d.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help you with markup you wrote but SO is not here to write markup for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method would be to apply `left:0px;` to the left `div` and `right:0px;` to the right `div`. Then you only have to set `position:fixed;` for both of them.